# Moving a misplaced title underneath its chemical structure in chemfig?

Tags: chemfig, chemistry

I can't seem to get the benzopinacol name under its specific molecule, the one circled in blue. Is there any way to fix this?

This is not only my first time using LaTeX but also my first time coding. So any help I can get would be appreciated.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
\schemedebug{false}
\setarrowdefault{0,1.5}
\schemestart
 \tiny\chemname{\chemfig{*6(=-(-[:315](-[:225] *6(=-=-=-))(=[:0]O))=-=-)}}{benzophenone}\+
  \chemname{\chemfig{OH-(-[:45])(-[:315])}}{2-propanol}\arrow{->[hv][AcOH(cat)]}
  \chemename{\chemfig{C(-[:90]Ph)(-[:225]Ph)(-[:315]OH)(-[:340](-[:90]Ph)(-[:315]OH)(-[:225]Ph))}}{benzopinacol}
\schemestop
\end{document}
```

[image: benzopinacol molecule in the blue circle]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in your code: `\chemename` should be `\chemname`. There is an error message in the log showing this:

```
./test.tex:10: Undefined control sequence.
\CF@compound ->\chemename 
                          {\chemfig {C(-[:90]Ph)(-[:225]Ph)(-[:315]OH)(-[:34...
l.10 \schemestop
```

---

A proposal with a few improvements/changes:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{showframe}% to demonstrate page dimensions so we can make sure the
                      % scheme doesn't overlap into the margins
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  \schemestart[0,1.5]% optional argument sets arrow defaults just for this scheme
    \chemname
      {\chemfig{[4,.75]O=(-[:-120]*6(=-=-=-))-[:120]*6(=-=-=-)}}
      {benzophenone}
    \+
    \chemname
      {\chemfig{[,.75]HO-(-[:60])-[:-60]}}
      {2-propanol}
    \arrow(.mid east--.mid west){->[$h\nu$][AcOH (cat)]}
    \chemname
      {%
        \chemfig{
          C(-[:90]Ph)(-[:225]Ph)(-[:-45,.75]OH)
          -[:340,1.33]
          C(-[:90]Ph)(-[:225]Ph)-[:-45]OH
        }%
      }
      {benzopinacol}
  \schemestop
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]